# Getting iPhone GO button to submit form

Tags: iphone, html, forms, keyboard

Is anyone aware of what variables go into a form to make the iPhones virtual keyboard's GO button submit the form vs. not?

I've been trying to narrow down the scenarios and this is what I've found:

- if FORM has only one user input field, go button automatically submits form
- if FORM has more than one user input field, but no INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" then the GO button does not submit the form.
- if FORM has more than one user input field AND has an INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" then the go button does submit the form.

However, that's not completely accurate, as we're running into a situation the 3rd isn't working for us.

Is anyone aware of the other factors that go into the GO button working vs. not working?

Comment: Extra info:
If FORM has a TEXTAREA field, and the user is typing in that, then a GO button is not shown. Im trying to find a solution

Comment: You need to have a action (can be non-specified), nothing else matters.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So, here was our specific issue:

We had a form with multiple user input fields, but not a true `<input type="submit">` (it was being submitted via JS).

As such, the GO button did nothing.

We then added an `<input type="submit">` and set it to `display: none` hoping that would do the trick. Nope. Didn't work.

On a whim, we changed display: none to `margin-left: -1000px`

That worked!

Apparently, Safari is looking for the presence of a SUBMIT button in the form and only if it's not display: none, it will then fire it when you hit the GO button.

Comment: We took the same approach, but instead of margin-left we just pushed it back using z-index and hide it under our graphical button by using some position relative fun.

Comment: Tried doing it with `visibilty:hidden;` this works, but obviously the button is then drawn on the screen but not shown... thus taking place and making my form ugly. Setting it to `position:absolute;` and `left:-1000px;` worked for me too

Comment: Beware of that "off screen" techniques ! With css 3d transforms websites (or websites using perspective etc.) even if the object is NOT display on the screen, the browser calculates it. It causes a (huge) drop down in performance (even on the famous text-indent: -9999px !). So I'll prefer the opacity:0/visibility:hidden solution

Comment: @Grsmto interesting point! In fact, I think I'm doing this on an iOS app at the moment. I need to double check that it's not rendering when doing the transformations...

Comment: <input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"/>

Comment: Ran into the same problem today. Went with `"position:absolute;left:-10000px"`

Answer (score 23):

If there are more than one inputs and you want to hide the submit, the best seems:

```
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"/>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Visibility: hidden makes the it not render the item and position absolute hides it but keep it within the page bounds!

Comment: There's a typo: visibility instead of visiblity.

Answer (score 4):

You can also bind a keypress listener to the element or form. The iphone "Go" button is the same as the enter button on a computer, char 13.

```
$('someElem').bind("keypress", function(e){
    // 'Go' key code is 13
    if (e.which === 13) {
       console.log("user pressed Go");
       // submit your form with explicit JS.
    } 
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not work out why a very simple google maps form was not submitting using the iPhone Go button.

Turns out, after stripping it down, it does not work with `target="_blank"` on the form tag.

Removed that, and now the Go button works on iPhone.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmujqrms/4/) to try it

Comment: I was about to say, that's silly, why would you ever have that on a form element, then I noticed, that was exactly my issue. I had copy/pasted a form from Mailchimp and it had that attribute on it.

Answer (score 1):

The code given by the others is correct.
If you are using jQuery Mobile then add

```
data-role="none"
```

to the submit input element. Like so:

```
<input type="submit" data-role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As of writing (11/19/2019), on iOS 13.1.3, the following scenarios change the `return` key label:

- The `INPUT` element must be wrapped in a `FORM` element, and the `FORM` element must have an `action` attribute. (It can be an empty string, i.e. `action=""`.)
- If the `INPUT` element has a `type` of `search`, the return key have a label of `search`.
- Any other value for the `type` attribute will result in the return key having a label of `go`.

The presence of an `INPUT` or `BUTTON` element with a `type` set to `submit` does not appear to affect the return key label. (Though it's a good idea to include one for accessibility purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

Just enclosing my input type='search' in a form tag did the trick when I encountered this problem.  Hopefully it might help others that had this problem as well.

Comment: It appears a form with only one input field WILL submit automatically with the GO button...but not if there is more than one input field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the submit button style that worked for me, with minimum side-effects on the page:

```
.... style="width: 0px ; height: 0px" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

GO button to submit is a default behaviour of iOS and don`t try to hack the keyboard because UIKeyboard is runtime header, however you can inject JS for your html in runtime and prevent GO button behaviour (GO acts like a Enter key),

Try this,

```
    WKWebView *webView;  
    WKUserContentController *contentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];

    NSString *script1 = @"var isEnter = false;";
    WKUserScript *userScript1 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script1 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [contentController addUserScript:userScript1];

    NSString *script2 = @"function captureGoKey(e){if(isEnter){e.preventDefault();}isEnter = false;}";
    WKUserScript *userScript2 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script2 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [contentController addUserScript:userScript2];

    NSString *script3 = @"var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];";
    WKUserScript *userScript3 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script3 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [contentController addUserScript:userScript3];

    NSString *script4 = @"document.onkeypress = function(e){if(e.keyCode == 13){isEnter = true;}}";
    WKUserScript *userScript4 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script4 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [contentController addUserScript:userScript4];

    NSString *script5 = @"if(form.attachEvent){form.attachEvent('submit', captureGoKey);}else{form.addEventListener('submit', captureGoKey);}";
    WKUserScript *userScript5 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script5 injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [contentController addUserScript:userScript5];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    config.userContentController = contentController;

    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:config];
```