# How to customize default keyboard for email input type on HTML5 in iOS

Tags: iphone, html

I'm a newbie in developing web app by HTML5 in Mobile. I have a trouble now. 
As you know in HTML5, default keyboard will be shown in browser while you input data into email input type with dedicated @ symbol key and Go symbol key

For web app, I'm think the keyboards that popup are related to the html5 input type attribute and will be shown by browser in default and can't customize.

However, in Gmail, the Return symbol key will be shown instead of Go symbol key as default,
Any solutions for customize keyboard on web app in mobile like Gmail's keyboard ?  Please sharing if you have any ideas
Thank you for in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

All the input types are there, for example `<input type="tel" name="usrtel">` will trigger the number keyboard instead the full english keyboard. However, if you want customize keyboard like GMail or Chrome App, I think it's not possible with mobile Safari.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. However not Gmail app, when you open Gmail in browser, add a new address then keyboard are being shown with Return symbol key instead of Go symbol key. How to Gmail can customize like that ?

Comment: I found the reason: Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/uYSTP/3/, I have tested on my Phone and all inputs will show Go if there's a form to submit. Google is using TextArea, instead of Input field, this is why it is showing return.

More discussion on the GO button behavior can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665203/getting-iphone-go-button-to-submit-form

Comment: If you use TextArea, can you show @ symbol key ? I'm sure that it is not possible

Comment: I found a reason. I think that is ok. If you use a textfield with email input type attribute in a form to submit then GO symbol key will be shown
If you not include in a form then Return key will be shown. In this case, we can submit by Ajax, JQuery

Comment: Yes. I checked Google's code as well, on their mobile version they are using <input type="email">, but their entire site is without a <form> and everything is via AJAX.

Comment: I didn't believe that the problem that spent 2 days has been solved fortunately. Thank you for sharing