# UIWebView - change virtual keyboard 'Go' button text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page that is displayed in an UIWebView on an iPad app. The page has an input field, and when the user taps on it, the virtual keyboard popups up.

Currently, the keyboard has the blue 'Go' button. I would like to change the button text from 'Go' to 'Done' and I want to grey-out/disable the button until the user types in at least 1 char.

Is this possible with Javascript/jQuery mobile? I don't have access to the app.

Thanks.

Comment: `I don't have access to the app.` ...did you mean, you don't have access to the code?

Comment: I think he is only able to change the web page which is viewed within the app, but not the app itself...

Comment: Yes, that's right. We don't have access to the app code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Bu you can change some functionality of the keyboard in html.

- [Make the button submit your form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5665203/3346612)
- [Make another keyboard displayed](http://www.fabianpimminger.com/web-development/how-to-change-the-iphone-on-screen-keyboard-in-web-apps/)

More features should not be available without access to the app. Instead of greying out the button, you can validate the form before submitting it with jQuery.