# How to have Rails 5 submit the form if IOS keyboard 'go' button is pressed

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

A default, scaffolded Rails 5 form will 'submit' if a desktop user presses the Enter button while the cursor is in a non-textarea form field. (If in a textarea field of course pressing Enter just inserts a newline into the field.)

When the form is viewed on an iphone, when you are editing a non-textarea field (such as a name) there is a Go button on the keyboard which is expected to submit the form.

The question: How does one enable that behavior **by default on a Rails 5 app**, eg, create forms so that the "Go" button on an iphone will submit the form the user is working on?

INCORRECTLY MARKED AS DUPLICATE FOR A GENERIC IOS QUESTION THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH RAILS or RAILS FORMS. (Rails has myriad special issues such as default scaffolding of forms, authenticity tokens, etc. and **that** is what this question is about.)

Here is a sample form in HAML produced by simple_form:

```
.row
  %h4 #{resource_name.to_s.humanize} sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .row
    .row.form-inputs
      %div.col.l4.m6.s12
        = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true
      %div.col.l4.m6.s12
        = f.input :password, required: false
      %div.col.l4.m6.s12
        = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  .row
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, "Log in"
.row
  = render "#{resource_name.to_s}s/shared/links"
```

Here is the form html:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_admin" id="new_admin" action="/admins/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="XXXXXXX" /><div class='row'>
<div class='row form-inputs'>
<div class='col l4 m6 s12'>
<div class="input-field email optional admin_email">
<input class="string email optional" autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="admin[email]" id="admin_email" />
<label class="email optional" for="admin_email">Email</label></div>
</div>
<div class='col l4 m6 s12'>
<div class="input-field password optional admin_password">
<input class="password optional" length="128" type="password" name="admin[password]" id="admin_password" />
<label class="password optional" for="admin_password">Password</label></div>
</div>
<div class='col l4 m6 s12'>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='form-actions'>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log in" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" data-disable-with="Log in" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting iPhone GO button to submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665203/getting-iphone-go-button-to-submit-form)

Comment: not a dupe. that's generic IOS, not rails specific. Rails is not even mentioned on that quesiton or any of the answers, and the accepted answer is entirely irrelevant in a Rails context.

Comment: That answer is valid for anything that generates HTML. Rails generates HTML. It is a dupe. If you want code-specific information, why didn't you post your code?

Comment: Can you post the code of your form?

Comment: @Brad, frankly, cuz it's a Rails question, Rails has lots of defaults and I'm using them. So the question is aimed at Rails user who might look at the question (which has 'rails' in the title, unlike the other one) and say "oh, yeah, to get that to work change config.something to Foo. That's why. Nonetheless, html posted now. And no, the answer to "hide' the button by moving it off-screen with margin-left: -1000px is irrelevant to my quesiton. Did you read it? Or just knee-jerk react 'looks like a dupe'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using

```
= f.button :button
```

in simple_form forces simple_form to use the button tag (instead of input) which seems to eliminate any issues with the IOS keyboard 'Go' button.

That said, I had some trouble reproducing the original issue several days later, so it's possible using the input tag works fine too under most circumstances, but I've switched to using :button just to be sure.