# Search button on ios keyboard does not submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, typeahead.js

I coded a simple search form for my website using just a text input for the search term. Also i used the typeahead.js plugin which allows autocomplete while typing.

Everything seems to work fine except when i'm trying to submit the form using the **Search** button of the ios keyboard. When i tap it nothing happens.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Here is the form's code:

```
<form action="[config.site_url]/search/find" method="post" id="main-search-form"> 
    <div class="form-group" id="main-search">
        <input id="topnav_search" name="search_text" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" style="display: none;" />
</form>
```

And this is the search ios button that i mean:

[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference if you don’t hide the button?

Comment: Are you serious about the `[config.site_url]/search/find` action?

Comment: @Manngo The input field shouldn't be visible (Yes, i tried to make it visible but it didn't make any difference). Also, [config.site_url] is just a codeigniter variable which returns the site's url.

Comment: Hey your question asked already here : [iPhone search button to submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665203/getting-iphone-go-button-to-submit-form)

Comment: @DanielTaub Thanks Daniel!. I will check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i just changed the css styling of the submit button to this:

```
style="position: fixed; top: -1000px;"
```

Solution found here: [Getting iPhone GO button to submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665203/getting-iphone-go-button-to-submit-form)