# Disabling button upon submit not working on ios but fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, css, forms

To prevent some nervous user from submitting a form multiple times, I looked around for some solutions. The one I found is implemented below. Now, this works fine on a desktop browser, but on iOS devices it disables the button but never seems to actually submit the form. On a desktop my button color and text changes, the button gets disabled, and my controller takes over to process the input. On iOS I get the color change, the new text, the disabled button, but no controller input at all. Anyone had that same issue and found a fix? This is not an iOS GO button issue. The problem is that once the button is disabled, the form no longer processes (after the click) on iOS.

First thing I tried was to remove form.myButton.disabled = true; from my function and then the form processes fine on desktop and iOS, including button color and text; however, the button is not disabled and still allows multiple submissions.

I tried various other examples. If I pass it as an attribute (onsubmit) at form_open, then the disabling and submission works on desktop, but I am also including a class in my form_open and that no longer works, essentially breaking the form functionality entirely on IOS. If I use a simple one text field input as my form, the below approach works, but on a more complex form with mixed text and checkboxes, the output is broken on iOS (but not desktop).

e.g.: echo form_open(base_url('home/step_one'), array('onsubmit' => 'return checkForm(this)'), 'class="form-horizontal"');

```html
<?php echo form_open(base_url('home/step_one'), 'class="form-horizontal"');?>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="control-label">First and Last Name * </label>
    <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" value="<?=isset($signup)?$signup[" full_name "]:" ";?>" required />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="control-label">Email Address * </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?=isset($signup)?$signup[" email "]:" ";?>" required />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12 c_txt_right">
    <input id="submitting" type="submit" onclick="checkForm(this.form);" name="myButton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
    <button type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetForm(this.form);" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkForm(form) // Submit button clicked
  {
    form.myButton.disabled = true;
    form.myButton.value = "Please wait...";
    document.getElementById("submitting").className = "btn btn-warning";
    return true;
  }

  function resetForm(form) // Reset button clicked
  {
    form.myButton.disabled = false;
    form.myButton.value = "Submit";
    window.location.reload();
  }
</script>
<?php echo form_close( ); ?>
```

Comment: I'm curious if iOS is calling preventDefault on the event for some reason. Have you tried using the Safari debugger to catch any console errors or debug the code on mobile?

Comment: migrate to NOT do `onclick="checkForm(this.form);"` and instead add event listeners

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting iPhone GO button to submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665203/getting-iphone-go-button-to-submit-form)

Comment: Getting the Iphone GO button to submit is not my issue. I have an input and a submit button that is working. The problem is to prevent it from registering multiple clicks and my approach above does not work on iOS. I do not have access to a safari debugger to see what may happen. to be clear: the form works as expected but as soon as I use disabled true the button still clicks and registers but the form is no longer submitted (only on iOS).

Comment: FYI: the solution to this issue is to use form_open with an attribute array and include onsubmit to call the JS function instead of onclick. Then the button is correctly disabled and the form submits on iOS.